# Populate the record links using Recursive CTE

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the contact table records which has a link of other contact record or the contact record is not linked to anything (null)

As per below example id 21 is a parent for contact 1

[image]

I need to populate the temptable using T-SQL records (Using the recursive CTE) with all the contact links for the each and every contact id in contact table as below
As one contact id is associated with multiple contact ids, the Link1,Link2,link3 columns should be dynamically created if possible.

[image]

Could anybody please help me with this script

Comment: So, 1 is linked to 21, I'm assuming 21 is linked to 4, but 4 is linked to 1 in the sample data, and to 8 in the desired results, so I'm not sure my assumption is correct. Please [edit] your question to include sample data as DDL+DML, desired results that actually fit the data, and what you have tried so far.

Comment: 21 is linked to 1 and 1 is linked to 4. So For Contact 1, 21 is the first link and then 4 is the second link  and 8 is the third link. As I will be checking the contact id from contact 1, contact id's 4,21 and 8 are the links. hope this makes sense

Comment: Kinda.... Again, sample data as DDL+DML would help us help you.

Comment: And also, contact id 2 does not have any link or contact ld is not being used as link in any contact id's, that is why the link 1-5 does not have any value.

Comment: Sorry This is just drafted one. There is no actually data exists as described above.

Comment: Well if you want to have an answer you can use, you should make sure your question actually reproduces whatever problem you try to solve...

Answer (score 0):

Try this (necessary remarks in comments):

```
--data definition
declare @contactTable table (contactId int, linkContactId int)
insert into @contactTable values
(1,21),
(2,null),
(3,450),
(4,1),
(5,900),
(6,5),
(7,3),
(8,1)
--recursive cte
;with cte as (
    (select 1 n, contactId from @contactTable
    where linkContactId = 1
    union
    select 1, linkContactId from @contactTable
    where contactId = 1)

    union all
    --this part might seem confusing, I tried writing recursive part similairly as anchor part,
    --but it needed to joins, which isn't allowed in recursive part of cte, so I worked around it
    select n + 1,
           case when cte.n + 1 = t.contactId then t.linkContactId else t.contactId end
    from cte join @contactTable [t] on
    (cte.n + 1 = t.contactId or cte.n + 1 = t.linkContactId)
)
--grouping results by contactId concatenating all linkContacts
select n [contactId],
       (select distinct cast(contactId as varchar(5)) + ',' from cte where n = c.n for xml path(''), type).value('(.)[1]', 'varchar(100)') [linkContactId]
from cte [c]
group by n
```

Comment: Sorry, This does not work with my data set. Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you help me with building the below logic by the cursor Atleast. So I can get my desired results for now.

Answer (score 0):

As per your above script i was able to nearly get the results

[image]

As 4,8 have already been included in the first row, it should not be shown as seperate record/records

Can you please adjust your query and please provide me the skipping script